# File not uploading successfully to FTP

Tags: java, apache, ftp, apache-commons

I have written a stand alone Program to upload file to FTP Server. Code runs fine but I cannot find the file at FTP. Here is the code

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.SocketException;

import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPReply;


public class FTPDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();
        int reply;

        try {

            ftp.connect("ip address");
            ftp.login("username","password");
            reply = ftp.getReplyCode();

            if(FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)){
                System.out.println("Connected Success");
            }else {
                System.out.println("Connection Failed");
                ftp.disconnect();
            }

            FileInputStream fis = null;
            String filename = "demo.txt";
            fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\demo.txt");
            System.out.println("Is file stored: "+ftp.storeFile(filename,fis));
            fis.close();
            ftp.disconnect();
        } catch (SocketException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Is file stored returns false. What could be the problem ?

Comment: Use the method getReplyCode() to get the ftp exact ftp error code. Then we can investigate the causes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me quote you the [FTPClient documentation](http://commons.apache.org/net/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#storeFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.io.InputStream%29):

> The convention for all the FTP command methods in FTPClient is such that they either return a boolean value or some other value. The boolean methods return true on a successful completion reply from the FTP server and false on a reply resulting in an error condition or failure. The methods returning a value other than boolean return a value containing the higher level data produced by the FTP command, or null if a reply resulted in an error condition or failure. If you want to access the exact FTP reply code causing a success or failure, you must call getReplyCode after a success or failure.

In other words, to understand the actual reason for failure you need to call `ftp.getReplyCode()` and work from there.

Comment: I believe Reply code is correct as I can see message on the console "Connected Success".

Comment: Yes, but check what getReplyCode() is returning after your storeFile() call.

Comment: Reply code is 230 before storeFile() is called and it is 500 after storeFile.

Comment: From this page here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FTP_server_return_codes

`500 Syntax error, command unrecognized. This may include errors such as command line too long.`

Try these before making the storeFile call:
`ftp.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE, FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
ftp.setFileTransferMode(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);`

Comment: I used the above methods that you specified it still not creating file at the FTP. Reply code are same 230 before and 500 after storeFileCall() call.

Comment: Are you able to ftp a file to same location using some other client like Filezilla for example?

Comment: Hi,
Finally after so long I am able to find the error. The password for the FTP contains special characters due to which the URL that is passed in the "ftp.connect("ip address");" is not valid. I found that if password contains special characters you need to replace those special characters and then it works fine.

Comment: Ravi Kumar i am having the same problem can you please elaborate what you did?